# Angular Component not getting called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular12

I am trying to load a toast message on load of a page.

I have added my component in the **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LandingComponent,
    ToastMessagesComponent
  ],
```

And I have created a **toastMessageService** for the toastMessage (fileName - **toastMessageService.ts**)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastMessageService {

  private readonly toastSubject = new Subject<ToastMessageState>();
  toastState = this.toastSubject.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  show(status: string, message: string) {
    console.log("hello Inside toast message");
    this.toastSubject.next({
      show: true,
      status,
      message
    } as ToastMessageState);
  }
  hide() {
    this.toastSubject.next({
      show: false
    } as ToastMessageState);
  }
}
```

**toastMessageState.ts**

```
export interface ToastMessageState {
    show: boolean;
    status: string;
    message: string;
}
```

I have declared the below code in **app.component.ts** so that it can call the **toastMessageService** when the app gets loaded

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside App Component****");
    this.toastMessageService.show("success", "hello");
  }
```

the **show** method is getting called from the **service** but the from there the expectation to call the **component** so it can load the html & css that it has and show a pop-up from the **component**

**toastMessageComponent.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
// import {ToastMessageService} from '../../../../services/toastMessage/toast-message.service';
import {ToastMessageState} from './toastMessageState';
import {ToastMessageService} from "../../services/toastMessage/toast-message.service";
import {LandingFormService} from "../../services/landing-form.service";
// import {CONSTANT} from '../../../../app.constants';

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-portal-toast-messages',
    templateUrl: './toast-messages.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./toast-messages.component.css'],
    providers: [ToastMessageService]
})
export class ToastMessagesComponent implements OnInit {

    status: any;
    message: any;
    show = false;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private toastMessageService: ToastMessageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log("In it Method for toast-message component");
        this.subscription = this.toastMessageService.toastState
            .subscribe((state: ToastMessageState) => {
                this.show = state.show;
                this.status = state.status;
                this.message = state.message === undefined && state.status === "failure" ?
                    "Internal Server Error" : state.message;
            });
        this.toastMessageService.show("success", "hello world!");
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

If I replace the existing working component in the **app-routing.module.ts** then it loads up fine. But if I call the service from app.component.ts then the **component** is not getting called.

Any help on this on what went wrong here, tried many ways but didn't work out.

**thanks**

Comment: ngAfterViewInit work better than ngOnInit?

Comment: You really need to break this down. There are various places this could go wrong and you could help us help you by telling us the following information. Is the success block in the subscribe block being called? Is the error block in the subscribe block being called? Also an Observable should have a $ at the end like this ... toastState$ ... when show is true what should happen? do we need to see your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your component is not getting instantiated, hence the `ToastMessagesComponent`'s `ngOnInit` is never invoked.

You need to "use" you component in `app.component.html`, like so,

```html
... the HTML for you app file

<admin-portal-toast-messages></admin-portal-toast-messages>
```

It is working fine if you update the route in your `app-routing.module.ts` file because the router instantiates the component when the route is activated.

Keep in mind that declaring a component does not mean it will get instantiated, declaration just makes it available across the module.